# Cannot find my search "iso" in a word "TESTISOTEST" by using FREETEXTTABLE

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, freetexttable

First, i'm starting to implement a fulltext search on a table of 12 millions of rows.
So maybe I have not yet understood all of its intricacies. :)

All those 12 millions of rows seem to indexed correctly and my index is correctly created with 1036 as LCID Language. I use the "SYSTEM" Stopwords list and this one seems to be empty. That's ok for me, for now.

Query used is like that :

```
DECLARE @Keywords nvarchar(2800)
SET @Keywords = 'iso'

SELECT FT.[Key], DS.Data, DS.DataTypeId
FROM DatasSearch_fr AS DS
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(DatasSearch_fr, (Data), ''' + @Keywords + ''', LANGUAGE 1036) AS FT  ON FT.[Key] = DS.Id
ORDER  BY DS.DataTypeId DESC
```

This query used in a SP returned all datas with `"ISO"` value or `"TEST ISO TEST"` value but not with `"TESTISOTEST"` or `"ISOTEST"`...

Maybe it's the correct operation of the full-text search with `FREETEXTABLE`. 
But i would like to know how returned this "`TESTISOTEST`" type of data. Maybe by using `CONTAINSTABLE` but it seems to me really not useful...

Thanks for your help,
Regards,
Sébastien

Answer (score 0):

Fulltext search depends on tokenizing the input text, usually  this is done at word boundaries (for Western languages). So you cannot find arbitrary substrings, only words.

Comment: So, for you it's not a trouble... This is the correct one full-text search result.

Comment: For a default configuration of full-text-search it "works as specified". You have to decide what you need and choose and configure the tools accordingly.

Comment: Thank for your help Thilo.
When you say "configure the tools accordingly", you think "use freetextable / containstable / ..." ?